# Clickable URLs: no click possible after the line break

Tags: line-breaking, urls, links

I use `\url` to make an URL clickable. When the line breaks, the part of the URL after the line break is not clickable. Why, and how to fix it?

Demo:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{url}
 \begin{document}
\url{http://google.com}

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \url{http://google.com}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I observed this behavior with the built-in Google Chrome PDF Viewer and Sumatra PDF on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) does a better job at managing line-breaks in URLs:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  hidelinks, % Remove visible links altogether
  %urlbordercolor = 1 1 1% Make URL link border white
}

\begin{document}

\url{http://google.com}

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \url{http://google.com}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

You can remove the borders using the `hidelinks` option, or set the border colour for URLs specifically to white (`1 1 1`).

Comment: It works great, thanks! As a positive side effect, it also made the URL clickable in Adobe Reader. Just a small typo: there should be no `,` after `hidelinks` (I cannot edit due to SE bitching about edit size)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: There is no real harm in leaving the `,` there, as a key-value setting allows for empty items in a list.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `url` package does not make the link clickable, it only formats it and allow it to break in a sensible place.  However, some pdf readers will parse the text and if a url is detected will allow the user to click on the link, but that link is not part of the pdf. `hyperref` on the other hand, does create clickable links and not only for urls but also for internal links such as references, toc, labels, etc... Additionally, `hyperref` will only allow to break links by default if the pdftex engine is used, if you are using latex>dvipdfm then you need the `breaklinks` option.

Comment: @ArTourter: Great remark. Yes, the fact that `.com` is not seen as part of the URL is a misinterpretation of the reader. [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) corrects this.